# Get an old commit in a subfolder

Tags: git

Well, it's pretty hard to explain but it's about GTK3 themes versions.
Before, we had

```
theme_name/
    gtk-2.0/
    gtk-3.0/
```

But GTK3.20 broke some themes so we *should* have done :

```
cp -R gtk-3.0/ gtk-3.20
#theme_name/
#    gtk-2.0/
#    gtk-3.0/
#    gtk-3.20/
# Modify the gtk-3.20 directory to match the new gtk release
git commit "copy and adapt to new version"
```

We didn't do the new folder.
So now we have the git tree :

```
* mv gtk-3.0 gtk-3.20, but we don't have the gtk-3.0 directory :(   
|
* 3.20 stable in the gtk-3.0 directory
|
* 3.18 stable in the gtk-3.0 directory (3.20 didn't exist)
```

How can I "merge" the old commit to get back the 3.18 release (but only the gtk3.20 directory) ?

I could do a copy-paste but it's not in the git spirit ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git checkout <branch where the move happened and that should be fixed>
git reset --hard <commit-ish of good version>
git merge --no-ff HEAD@{1}
git checkout HEAD@{1} -- theme_name/gtk-3.0
git commit --amend -m "bring back gtk-3.0"
```

Comment: That's the ticket. Checkout loads the index, so you don't need the add.

Comment: @jthill what do you mean? checkout with a commit-ish and a path does not update from the index but from the commit-ish

Comment: Do the checkout, then do `git status`, you'll see that it does update the index.

Comment: Looking at the doc I see it's not really clear on this, it's easy to see how how you held your original concept.

Comment: Really? After your comment I looked at the docs and found it pretty clear, I just didn't remember it: "The <tree-ish> argument can be used to specify a specific tree-ish (i.e. commit, tag or tree) **to update the index** for the given paths **before updating the working tree**."

Comment: Ah, but to get that you have to actually read it all, rather than just the topic sentence :-) -- seriously, git's got its own way of doing things and people tend to read what they expect to read.

Comment: Well, Git is growsn too complex to make assumptions on what you think it will do. :-D

Comment: Okay, that makes what I wanted but I had hoped for a tree showing the "merge" :)

Comment: What would the parent of the merge be? How do you imagine your history to look like?

Comment: The parents of the merge would be 3.18 and mv into gtk3.20.

Comment: Two more questions. **1.** What should be the first parent and what should be the second if it matters? **2.** And are there more commits after mv to 3.20, or are is this the tip of the branch?

Comment: Ok, updated the answer. I think now it should result in what you wanted to have.